# Count unique text values between dates that match 1 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a issue with this formula and i was looking everywhere, but i was not able to figure it out.  What i want to do with this formula is after the code is changed i need to know, how many unique models was used for this changed code

Formula is working only without `$A$2:$A$25000;F2` that means, i'm not able to say how many unique models i have for one code, but it's for all of them

[image]

Do you have any suggestions ? Thank you !

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(($C$2:$C$25000E2);1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$25000;F2;$C$2:$C$25000;"<="&E2+30; $C$2:$C$25000; ">"&E2;$B$2:$B$25000;$B$2:$B$25000&"");0))
```

Comment: `IF(($C$2:$C$25000E2)` doesn't look right for one...

Comment: Looks like you have missed a significant piece in your formula as what you written down, compared to what you have used in your sheet.

Comment: I made a mistake, i copied old formula `=SUMPRODUCT(IF(($C$2:$C$25000<E2+30)*($C$2:$C$25000>E2);1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$25000;F2;$C$2:$C$25000;"<="&E2+30; $C$2:$C$25000; ">"&E2;$B$2:$B$25000;$B$2:$B$25000&"");0))`